# Render AMP pages using react on server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amp-html

I have tried rendering the AMP page by generating the HTML on server using React.
I made a component which calls the API and renders the amp tags and other stuff. This component generates a plain html (which is amp like) inside server.js and I included all the scripts necessary for amp in server.js only.
On my local, this is giving the exact AMP-HTML which is needed, without showing any amp errors. I want to know, is this the right approach to do the same or should I use any templating engine like dot.js to implement this ?
If I carry on with the specified approach, can anyone tell, what can be the limitation of the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to use React for rendering AMP pages. Some React frameworks such as Next.js even feature [a dedicated AMP support](https://nextjs.org/docs#enabling-amp-support).